# Highmaps drill down map select event

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dom-events

I managed to create a map of Norway using 'Highmaps' (http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo) with Counties and when it select a county it will drill down to the municipalities. I need to catch the `select` event in the drill down and display some data according to the municipality. But could not find any events for drilldown.

Any Ideas?

Comment: In the website you linked there is a drilldown demo, in which you see drilldown events. You catch a selected country there - see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/k3z7r32m/)

Comment: That only triggers from parent map, not the drilled down map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of Highcharts helpdesk support.
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bydfsxe2/

```
// Set drilldown pointers
$.each(data, function (i) {
    this.drilldown = this.properties['hc-key'];
    this.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
});

// Instanciate the map
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
//call external function
                                    alert(e.point.drilldown);
//rest of the code
```